# Are there object-oriented databases with fulltext search out of the box?

Tags: database, search, database-design

My task ahead is to insert a giant amount of data into a document-oriented DB (any one of them) and have it be full-text searchable as a whole (on all or any field).

Do I have to use a DB and a separate full-text search index like Solr or are there document-oriented DBs with fulltext search kind of built-in?

Comment: I kind of need that too, have you found a suitable solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't know of any.  Full text search is a bit odd to put in an OODBMS paradigm-wise.  So I would approach this differently.

I would select PostgreSQL because:

- You can build hybrid document-oriented/relational databases on it using XML or JSOn for the document portion
- It is highly programmable so you should be able to integrate various full search options into the back-end if you need to
- It supports stored procedures written in a wide variety of languages including Perl, Java, and Python, and
- There are object-relational extensions to the database that make working with it easier in the context where you are looking for an OODBMS.  In essence you can build your database in PostgreSQL where a table is a class containing a set of objects, rather than as a set of rows.  The distinction is that you can then build sophisticated interfaces to your objects, including derived information, and the like.

The next thing I would do is evaluate the full text search out of the box.  If this meets your needs, go with it.  If not, then the next thing to do would be to integrate Lucene using PL/Java if that is practical.  If not, then you can put Lucene in a separate component of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can look in open source DB (Firebird, PostgreSQL or MySQL) and open source FullText Search engine (Lucene or Sphinx).

Generally separate full-text search index is quicker.